# How to prevent Bootstrap Modal from closing on GridView item click?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, aspxgridview

I have created a `GridView` inside of a modal with controls to add into the `GridView`. Everything works fine, however, every time I click the controls of the `Gridview`, the modal closes. Even if I select an element on the `Gridview` the modal will close. If I open the modal again, it will show the element that I've selected before the closing of the modal. Is there a way to do this? I've seen posts saying that I should include `data-backdrop:static` but does not work.

```
<section class="modal modalWindow" id="popupOne" style="margin-top: -137px; height: 581px; width: 941px; border: solid; margin-left: -627px; top: 25%; left: 65%">
    <section class="modalWrapper" style="height: 625px">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Credentialing</h1>

        <hr />

        <div class="card pmd-card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <!-- Basic Information -->
                <div class="details-tab">
                    <%--<div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-2">
                                                <h3 class="card-title media-body">Applicant Information</h3>
                                            </div>--%>
                        <div class="row view-basic-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Applicant ID</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbAppID" class="form-control" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                                <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Applicant Name</label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbFullName" class="form-control" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Contact Information -->
                <div class="details-tab">
                    <!-- View Card -->

                    <div class="row view-contact-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Document/Credential</label>
                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" runat="server" ID="tbDocType"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Date Received</label>
                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server" ID="tbDateReceived"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row view-contact-card" style="margin-bottom: 10px">

                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmitCred" OnClick="btnSubmitCred_Click" class="d-none d-sm-block btn btn-sm btn-success shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-sm text-white-50" style="padding-right:10px"></i>Add</asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRemoveCred" OnClick="btnRemoveCred_Click" class="d-none d-sm-block btn btn-sm btn-danger shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-sm text-white-50" style="padding-right:10px"></i>Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <asp:GridView class="table table-bordered" ID="gvAppCred" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CredID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnPageIndexChanging="gvAppCred_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvAppCred_OnRowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="CredID" HeaderText="CredID" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="CredID"></asp:BoundField>--%>
                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="AppID" HeaderText="AppID" SortExpression="AppID"></asp:BoundField>--%>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" Visible="false"></asp:CommandField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DocumentType" HeaderText="Document" SortExpression="DocumentType"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" HeaderText="Submission Date" SortExpression="SubmitDate"></asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#54a1e5" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="white" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRRecruitmentDBConn %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblCredential] WHERE ([AppID] = @AppID)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbAppID" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="xSelectedPersonID" Name="AppID" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <div class="form-row" style="justify-content: center; padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-lg btn-success shadow-sm modalButton" Style="margin-right: 15px"><i class="fas fa-backward fa-sm text-white-50"></i>Back</asp:LinkButton>
                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditCancel" runat="server" href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-lg btn-danger shadow-sm modalButton"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle fa-sm text-white-50"></i>Cancel</asp:LinkButton>--%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <a class="closeBtn">CLOSE X</a>
</section>
```

Comment: It is not data-backdrop, it is simply backdrop. Have you used this in your scripts? Try looking at this article here: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-modal-from-closing-when-clicking-outside.php Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried the script from the link you mentioned but still the modal closes upon selecting an item on the Gridview. My issue is just clicking in the GridView is causing the modal to close. Without the script, the modal doesn't close if I click outside. So I assume that solution does not work in my case.

Comment: I don't see any vb.net. Please correct tags.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the Modal, but the PostBack that happens when clicking a Control. Use an UpdatePanel in the Modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```